# Css background-image navigation bar

Tags: css, html

```
nav {
  padding : 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  background-image : url("This PC/Pictures/motivationportfolio.jpg");
}
li
{
 padding : 10px; 
}
div
{
  text-align : justify;
  margin : 20px;
}
p
{
  text-indent : 15px;
}
```

This code is not inserting background image to my navigation bar.you can check the entire code in http://codepen.io/Supreja/pen/zKERvd.
I have also tried giving the online URL . Even that doesnot work. I am working online ,so how to know my current directory ?

Comment: what is `../This PC` ?! It wont work online

Comment: You cannot access your own PC's files that way.

Answer (score 1):

That should work just paste a valid URL:

For instance:

```
background-image : url('http://www.verypdf.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/clip_image00455.jpg');
```

Answer (score 0):

well , you need to know where is the path of your image first.
for example you have images folder and CSS folder .
and this style is in the CSS folder , then the path should be like that
../images/iamgename.jpg

this two dots (..) make you back one step then enter images folder and choose your image

```
url("../Pictures/motivationportfolio.jpg");
```